# K3s - create user with client certificate

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, k3s

I've tried to create user accounts with a client certificate.

I followed two tutorials but stuck with both options in an error with the message

https://medium.com/better-programming/k8s-tips-give-access-to-your-clusterwith-a-client-certificate-dfb3b71a76fe

https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/

I set the right user, server and the right context. I set the namespace but still the same error.

```
> kubectl get pods
You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

Did someone already experienced something similar? Or does someone knows what i'm doing wrong?

My k3s cluster version is 1.15.4.

Comment: Are you able to login with the user you've just created?

Comment: I followed the setup, like written on this pages, but it looks like it differs to a k3s installation. Maybe i made a mistake, many times?! Not sure, if i'm blind and can't see what i did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found my answer in this ticket.

https://github.com/rancher/k3s/issues/684

The user huapox posted the following code:

```
[root@(⎈ |default:default) sec-rbac]$ cat t2.sh 
ws=/opt/sec-rbac
day=3650

clus_name="t1.k3s"
clus_ns="default"
user="koper"
#clus_url="https://10.200.100.183:7442"
clus_url="https://server:6443"  ##
ca_path=$ws/server/tls
rm -f $ca_path/*-ca.srl

ctx=gen && mkdir -p $ws/$ctx/{kube,keys} && cd $ws/$ctx
#############
ca1=client-ca
generate="keys/u-"$user
echo -e "\033[32m#>>GEN-KEY\033[0m"
#openssl genrsa -out $generate.key 2048
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out $generate.key
openssl req -new -key $generate.key -out $generate.csr -subj "/CN=${user}@${clus_name}/O=key-gen"
openssl x509 -req -in $generate.csr -CA $ca_path/$ca1.crt -CAkey $ca_path/$ca1.key -CAcreateserial -out $generate.crt -days $day

#-----------
#generate=$ca_path/client-admin  ##test
ca2=server-ca
embed=false
ctx2="$user@$clus_name"
config="kube/$user.kubeconfig"
echo -e "\033[32m#>>KUBE-CONFIG\033[0m" 
kubectl --kubeconfig=$config config set-cluster $clus_name --embed-certs=$embed --server=$clus_url --certificate-authority=$ca_path/$ca2.crt
kubectl --kubeconfig=$config config set-credentials $user --embed-certs=$embed --client-certificate=$generate.crt  --client-key=$generate.key
kubectl --kubeconfig=$config config set-context $ctx2 --cluster=$clus_name --namespace=$clus_ns --user=$user
kubectl --kubeconfig=$config config set current-context $ctx2
kubectl --kubeconfig=$config --context=$ctx2 get pods
```

Big thanks to huapox.

Answer (score 4):

From the error you posted, your user is getting failed in Authentication phase only (HTTP error code: **401**), you can validate the same using:

```
$ k get pods -v=6
...
I0123 16:34:18.842853   29373 helpers.go:203] server response object: [{
  ...
  "code": 401
}]
F0123 16:34:18.842907   29373 helpers.go:114] error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

Debug your setup using below steps:

1. Verify you are using the correct context and correct user as you expected (with * in CURRENT column):

   ```
   $ kubectl config get-contexts 
   CURRENT   NAME                          CLUSTER      AUTHINFO                NAMESPACE
   *         context-user-ca-signed        kubernetes   user-user-ca-signed     ns1
             kubernetes-admin@kubernetes   kubernetes   kubernetes-admin
   ```
2. Verify the CA certificate for Kubernetes API Server (assuming API server running as a Pod):

   ```
   $ sudo cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml | grep -i "\-\-client-ca-file"
       - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt

   $ openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt -text -noout | grep -i "Issuer:\|Subject:"
           Issuer: CN = kubernetes
           Subject: CN = kubernetes
   ```
3. Verify your user's certificate is signed by above CA (Issuer CN of user's cert is same as Subject CN of CA cert, "kubernetes" here), which is configured in API server:

   ```
   $ kubectl config view --raw -o jsonpath="{.users[?(@.name == \"user-user-ca-signed\")].user.client-certificate-data}" | base64 -d > client.crt

   $ openssl x509 -in client.crt -text -noout | grep -i "Issuer:\|Subject:"
           Issuer: CN = kubernetes
           Subject: C = IN, ST = Some-State, O = Some-Organization, CN = user-ca-signed
   ```

If the above steps are fine for the user you created, you shall pass [Authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) phase.
But [Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/) phase still needs to be configured using RBAC, ABAC or any other supported authorization mode, else you may still get HTTP error code: **403**

```
$ kubectl get pods -v=6
I0123 16:59:41.350501   28553 helpers.go:203] server response object: [{
  ...
  "code": 403
}]
F0123 16:59:41.351080   28553 helpers.go:114] Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "user-ca-signed" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "ns1": No policy matched.
```

Comment: Hello Ramesh, first of all thank you very much for your detailed answer. Unfortunately the config files in k3s are a bit different. I found the following file, which is hopefully the pendant to the default kubernetes installation. Found the file here:
`/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/cred/api-server.kubeconfig`

But it doesn't contains the client-ca-file entry. Instead i have a `client-certificate: /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/tls/client-kube-apiserver.crt` and a `certificate-authority: /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/tls/server-ca.crt`

Comment: Oh, and the issuere in the client-kube-apiserver.crt is another one. Funny part is, that i requested a csr with kubectl itself and approved it as well. Extracted the crt then, but the outcome is still another one.